# Vue router navigation to the same route fails

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Code snippet can be found in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ParachuteKadse/d6fbzr0L/), sorry for posting code externally, stackoverflow code block always returns a `Server Error in '/' Application` when I click the navigation links.

Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Click on Foo
2. Click Foo-3
3. Scroll up
4. Repeat step 2

The expected behaviour is to scroll down to Foo-3, like the first time, but it actually stays at the same position and doesn't scroll to Foo-3.

How can I force it to scroll to Foo-3 if I click Foo-3 first and scroll up and click Foo-3 again in this case?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Code snippet didn't work in stackoverflow because of the path error in stackoverflow, please refer to js fiddle link I posted. I didn't create this code, but I am having the exactly same issue here. I didn't find the solution on Github, so I come here to ask for help. If there are any issues, please shout out.

[Code credit](https://jsfiddle.net/user/ParachuteKadse/fiddles/)

[Original question in Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1668)

```js
var FooComponent = {
  template: '#foo-template'
};
var routes = [{
  path: '/foo',
  component: FooComponent
}];
var scrollBehavior = function(to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return {
      selector: to.hash
    }
  } else {
    return {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  }
};
var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes,
  scrollBehavior: scrollBehavior,
  mode: 'history'
});
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app-root',
  router: router
});
```

```html
<div id="app-root">
  <h1>Issue Reproduction</h1>
  <router-link to="/foo">Foo</router-link>
  <h2>Nav</h2>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="foo-template">
  <section>
    <router-link :to="{path: '/foo', hash: 'foo-1'}">Foo-1</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{path: '/foo', hash: 'foo-2'}">Foo-2</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{path: '/foo', hash: 'foo-3'}">Foo-3</router-link>
    <h2 id="foo-1">Foo-1</h2>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <h2 id="foo-2">Foo-2</h2>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <h2 id="foo-3">Foo-3</h2>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
    <p>???</p>
  </section>
</script>
```

Comment: Even if you code doesn't run in the StackOverflow snippet, it's still better to include your code here.

Comment: Sure, will add it in a sec.

Comment: What you're really asking is how to jump to a position when the hash in the link already matches the URL

Comment: Exactly. Not just for hash link, if click on the same page link, normal web page behaviour is to reload the page, but when using vue router, it literally does nothing if the link already matches the URL, just wondering how to make it work like normal web page :)

Comment: has anyone found any solution?

Answer (score -1):

It is usual when using fragment identifiers, not limited to Vue.js. You can resolve this problem by altering the hash. Here's [a simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/d6fbzr0L/79/) in which the issue will not be reproduced.

In the demo, I added a listener in order to listen to scroll event and let the hash change based on the last element went through.

I hope it can give you a hint.

```
var FooComponent = {
  template: '#foo-template',
  mounted() {
    const switchHash = () => {
     Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h2')).forEach(h2 => {
       if(h2.offsetTop < window.pageYOffset && h2.offsetTop + h2.clientHeight > window.pageYOffset) {
         window.location.hash = h2.id;
       }
     });
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', switchHash);
  }
};
```

Comment: This solution has a terrible usability on Firefox. This browser jumps to each anchor when it changes, so when the user scrolls the page, it will keep jumping.